# Trouble Installing Drivers

Tags: drivers

I'm looking to install drivers for some old telephone tech. I'm in the UK and running Windows 7 professional on a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 laptop. I  can't see any .exe file in the driver link after I download it. 
Here's the link:http://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=21793

The drivers are for a PCMCIA card. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you noticed the compatibility? WinXP and below only. You need a newer driver

Answer (score 0):

I see two Setup.exe files within the .zip archives. You will have to unzip the .zip archives to get to the executables, which can be done using Windows' integrated unarchiving tool, or [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)